# MySql Two Tables Same Name Different Casing

Tags: mysql

I'm starting to freak out because I seem to have a phantom table... it's not showing up in Navicat however if I run these two queries:

`SELECT count(*) from messages;`

`SELECT count(*) from Messages;`

I get two different sets of results!

However, the weird thing is if i run `show tables` I only see one table called `messages`

This freaks me out because i have no clue if data is going to mistakenly get throwing into the incorrect table `Messages`

Has anyone ever seen this before?

I'm not sure what to do.

**Per Request**

After running `show table status like 'messages';`

`messages   InnoDB  10  Compact 224163  222 49889280    0   53608448    8388608 208683  2014-08-23 20:16:11         latin1_swedish_ci`

**One more update**

I've ran both:

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'Messages';`

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'messages';`

It's showing multiple records with different record counts

The scary part is I ran the same query for other tables in the database and all the other tables i tested with the same technique had the same problem.

It's as if I have two copies of each table, one with a capital first letter, the other with a lowercase, and it seems that the lowercase is the "freshest" of the two.

Comment: Windows or Linux/OSx? MySQL is case sensitive or not based on the underlying file system, for Linux, OSx, BSD etc this will be case sensitive, on windows this will be case intensive and can cause confusion over what a table is named.

Comment: The only problem is I cannot find the `Messages` table anywhere, not via show tables, not when looking in the actual data directory - yet I can still query it for different results.

Comment: OK, if you're running on windows they're probably the same table, `MESSAGES`, `MeSsAgEs` and `mESSAGES` should all reference the same table, as for different result, if you add an order by clause are they the same results then? It's possible MySQL is just ordering the results by whatever it likes and just happens to have picked different default sorting methods of the two cases of the table name.

Comment: No that's whats even more weird, I ran a COUNT(*) - totally different results.

Comment: Is there any chance you could run `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'messages'` and post the output into your original post?

Comment: Try `SHOW DATABASES`; with much luck the table is in another database. And then there exists `RENAME TABLE Messages TO Mess`

Comment: but see thats the thing, i originally stumbled upon this oddity when i was querying a specific database - and all my count queries that return different results were directed at 1 specific database, unless i'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Ooh, InnoDB, it's possible you've got the table cached in some strange way, could you try clearing the cache for it and see what happens then? `set global key_buffer_size=0; set global key_buffer_size=DEFAULT`

Comment: I'm going to reboot this server later tonight and see if that clears any weird caching issues that may cause this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you check for the table using a query of `information_schema.tables`.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'Messages';
```

Also consider the possibility that someone created a view.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.views  WHERE table_name = 'Messages';
```

---

There's a MySQL variable **`lower_case_tables_names`** that has an effect; the default value for this variable depends on the OS (Linux, Windows, OS X). (We have that explicitly set to 1 on our MySQL systems.) According to the reference manual:

**"If you are using InnoDB tables, you should set this variable to 1 on all platforms to force names to be converted to lowercase."**

(This section of the manual is does not describe the behavior you'd observe with InnoDB tables if this variable were set to something other than 1.)

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

Comment: The view might be the answer here.

Comment: I checked - no views - i will check the lower_case_table_names variable

Comment: I think you are getting closer... I ran the query above, one for Messages and one for messages - both return results... now the question is how the heck did i end up w/ two tables named the same w/ casing differences.. so odd!

Comment: If i change the variable to 1, will the lowercase tables remain the "primary" tables - what happens to the other tables? are they deleted?

Comment: @99823 Do a `show full tables;`, the column "Table_type" will tell you if and which one is a view.

Comment: @99823: That's a really good question. I'm not sure what all the fallout would be if you made a change to the `lower_case_table_names` variable now... I expect any tables with mixed case names wouldn't be accessible. (We have the `innodb_file_per_table` variable set, and all of our InnoDB tables are separate .idb files. If your InnoDB are all together in a shared InnoDB tablespace, I don't know... you might want to ask this question on **dba.stackexchange.com**.  If it were me, I'd be looking at getting some mysqldumps, tables with lower case table names, tables with mixed case names...

Comment: Yea - i'm going to do it some late night... backup everything and test it out on our dev server first. one weird thing i just noticed, its almost as if the tables "sync" after so long... so freakin weird... the record counts are now the same, when they were not prior...